# Remove extra characters in a string

Tags: r

I have a column that looks like this:

```
Item_Number

R8934nr  fd
4hgsi32df 
Miognse daf
```

I only want to keep the first 7 characters and remove the rest. I am new to R and I tried:

```
gsub(Item_Number, '', '[7]')
```

Comment: Use `substr(x, 1, 7)`

Comment: By characters your mean only characters in the alphabet? So you also want to get rid of all the numbers in your string?

Comment: Both answers below are good. Tim's is pretty much a one-liner though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sub` is one option, as you suggested.  This answer uses a pattern to selectively remove everything except for the up to first 7 characters of the string.

```
Item_Number = "1234567890"
sub("(?<=^.{7}).*", "", Item_Number, perl=TRUE)
[1] "1234567"
```

### Demo

Comment: or `sub("(.{7}).*", "\\1", Item_Number)`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I've been brainwashed by various top regex people on the site into thinking that capture groups are evil.  Well, there is an overhead to using them, but readability counts for something too, right?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know they were evil, I'm quite new (and late) to regex, I'll pay attention

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to keep characters something like this would do it.

```
your.string <- "R8934nr  fd"
your.string <- gsub(" ","",your.string)
your.string <- gsub("[[:digit:]]+","",your.string)
your.string <- substr(your.string,1,7)
```

Comment: Maybe stating the obvious but not to confuse new users: `substr` is the reasonable way to go, anything else is just regex fun.

Comment: see also `stringr::str_sub` which is pretty much the same but with default arguments, negative indice support, and can take a matrix as its first argument, or `stringi:stri_sub` which is almost the same.